# Why are non underscore names reserved to the implementation for UDL and not the other way around?

Tags: c++, user-defined-literals

I know this is an old feature but reading on [**user defined literals**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn919277.aspx) e.g.

```
return_t operator "" _a(long); // Literal operator for user-defined INTEGRAL literal
```

I was reminded that

> the leading underscore is required. (Only the Standard Library is allowed to define literals without the underscore.) (A)

**This seems to break pattern** since so far the implementation worked with the underscorey names and left us the good ones, for example reserved to the implementation are names that

1. Contain a double underscore
2. Begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter

Furthermore quote (A) is somewhat dangerous in the presence of rule (2). **So why the inconsistency**?

Comment: This is so we can get the "natural" looking suffixes in the standard library, and leave user-defined suffixes clearly visible as such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before the idea of user-defined literals was added to the language, all the standard literals used sequences that don't begin with underscore, such as `123L` for a `long int` literal. So to maintain consistency, standard literals get the namespace without any special prefix, and UDLs are distinguished from them by using `_`.